# Dispose DataContext in local database

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I work with local database in Windows Phone. Is required calling Dispose() to release resources and how best to do it?

```
using (DataContext context = new DataContext(DBConnectionString))
      {
           //
           context.SubmitChanges();
           context.Dispose();
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `using` here calls `Dispose()` (no matter whether it leaves normally or via an `Exception`). You don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

The `using` block that you are using in your example automatically ensures that `.Dispose()` will be called when the block is finished executing. If you were not using that keyword, you would have to manually call `Dispose()` yourself.

Take a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for a description of what the `using` statement does.

On another note, `DataContext` might not be the best name for your context, as that means something else to a lot of .NET developers.

Answer (score 2):

Dispose() is called by itself. You dont need to call it.

As a rule:-

> "acquire a resource as late as possible, release it as soon as its
>   safe"

i.e., You should consider your `DataContext` as a resource.